# Prove that concave functions are quasi-integrable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

**Exercise:** Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal B (\mathbb R))$ with $ \int |x| \,d\mu<\infty$. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be concave. Then $\int f \,d\mu$ exists in $[-\infty,\infty)$. If $f$ is bounded below, then $f$ is $\mu$-integrable.

My attempt:

Concave functions are continuous, so $f$ is measurable. From concavity of $f$ we have the inequalities

$$f(y)\leq f(x)+f'_+(x)(y-x)$$

$$f(y)\leq f(x)+f'_-(x)(y-x)$$

holding for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$, where $f'_+,f'_-$ denote the right and left derivatives of $f$ respectively. In particular there exists $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that

$$f(x)\leq g(x):=a+bx$$

for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Since $x$ is $\mu$-integrable, so is $g$. From $f^+\leq g^+$ we get

$$\int f^+ \, d\mu \leq \int g^+ \, d\mu<\infty$$

so $\int f \, d\mu=\int f^+ \, d\mu-\int f^- \, d\mu$ is defined in $[-\infty,\infty)$.

If $f$ is bounded below, say $c\leq f$, then $f^-\leq -\min \{c,0\}$ so $\int f^- \, d\mu<\infty$ as well.

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Not missing anything - this is correct

Comment: @user6247850 Thank you for your feeback very appreciated.